# pgfplots: help with macro to drop line to x-axis

Tags: pgfplots, macros

I frequently produce plots where I need to label points on a function, which I prefer to do both using `x ticks` and by dropping a dashed line from the point down to the x-axis. I decided to write a macro to automate this, which will draw a line from the point to its projection on the x-axis, correcting for `ymin`. However, the lines that result from the macro don't end at the x-axis (and they end at different places from each other), and I can't figure out why. I suspect I need `axis cs:` somewhere, but no place I try seems to work.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\newcommand{\vertLineFromPoint}[1]{\draw[dashed] let \p1 = (#1) in (#1) -- 
(\x1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin})}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=left,
            ymin=20,
            extra x ticks={1,3},
            extra x tick labels={$x_1$, $x_2$},
        ]

        \addplot+[mark=none,name path=sqr] {(x-5)^2+50}; 
        \addplot+[mark=none,name path=lin] {10*x+100};

        \coordinate (x1) at (axis cs:1,66);
        \vertLineFromPoint{x1};

        \node (x2) at (axis cs:3,54) {};
        \draw[dashed] (x2.center) -- (axis cs:3,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin});

        \path[name intersections={of=sqr and lin}];
        \vertLineFromPoint{intersection-1};

        \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Resulting figure:

[image]

Note that it works for `x2`, where I do the `ymin` calculation in the axis instead of in the macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your command is that it returns the coordinates for the final point in terms of TikZ units which are different from the `axis` units. You can fix this by saying

```
\newcommand{\vertLineFromPoint}[1]{
  \draw[dashed] 
    (#1) -- (#1|-{axis cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}})
}
```

In particualr, there's no need for the calc library since all is done using the perpendicular coordinate system.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\newcommand{\vertLineFromPoint}[1]{
  \draw[dashed] 
    (#1) -- (#1|-{axis cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}})
}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=left,
            ymin=20,
            extra x ticks={1,3},
            extra x tick labels={$x_1$, $x_2$},
        ]

        \addplot+[mark=none,name path=sqr] {(x-5)^2+50}; 
        \addplot+[mark=none,name path=lin] {10*x+100};

        \coordinate (x1) at (axis cs:1,66);
        \vertLineFromPoint{x1};

        \node (x2) at (axis cs:3,54) {};
        \draw[dashed] (x2.center) -- (axis cs:3,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin});

        \path[name intersections={of=sqr and lin}];
        \vertLineFromPoint{intersection-1};

        \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Note that you can omit `axis cs` if you write `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` (or newer).