# pgfplots: macro to draw lines from point to y-axis

Tags: pgfplots, draw

After reading [pgfplots: help with macro to drop line to x-axis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269095), I was wondering if I could do the same thing but with a line connecting the point with its y-axis projection. So I tried to modify the macro as follows:

Vertical solution (from previous question):

```
\newcommand{\vertLineFromPoint}[1]{
      \draw[dashed] 
      (#1) -- (#1|-{axis cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}})
}
```

Horizontal (from me):

```
\newcommand{\horLineFromPoint}[1]{
   \draw[dashed] 
   (#1) -- (#1-|{axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0})
}
```

This gave me the impression to work properly, but I don't know why the line stops before reaching the y-axis, so the result is a horizontal dashed line from the right point to some random point on the right y-coordinate but wrong abscissa... as if the value of `xmin` was wrong.

The complete code:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}

...

\newcommand{\vertLineFromPoint}[1]{
  \draw[dashed] 
  (#1) -- (#1|-{axis cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}})
}
\newcommand{\horLineFromPoint}[1]{
  \draw[dashed] 
  (#1) -- (#1-|{axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0})
}

...

   \begin{figure}
        \hspace{-0.5cm}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
                \begin{semilogxaxis}[
                extra x ticks={3000},
                extra x tick labels={$\omega_p$},
                legend pos = south west,
                title=LP FIlter,
                xlabel={$\omega$ log [rad/s]},
                ylabel={$\phi$ [degrees]},
                xmin= 10^0, xmax=10^5,
                ymin=-90,ymax=90
                ]

                \addplot[blue] table{LPtheoryphase.dat};
                \addplot[mark=*,color=blue] coordinates {(3000,-45)};
                \vertLineFromPoint{3000,-45};
                \horLineFromPoint{3000,-45};
                \end{semilogxaxis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

But the output is the following:

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! Your macro seems to work fine here, can you add a complete example to your question?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `rel axis cs:0,0` instead of `axis cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}` this works fine. Note that without  `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}` (any version number of 1.11 or higher is the same) you would have to add `axis cs:` before `#1` in the macros.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\newcommand{\vertLineFromPoint}[1]{
  \draw[dashed] 
  (#1) -- (#1|-{rel axis cs:0,0})
}
\newcommand{\horLineFromPoint}[1]{
  \draw[dashed] 
  (#1) -- (#1-|{rel axis cs:0,0})
}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
                \begin{semilogxaxis}[
                extra x ticks={3000},
                extra x tick labels={$\omega_p$},
                legend pos = south west,
                title=LP FIlter,
                xlabel={$\omega$ log [rad/s]},
                ylabel={$\phi$ [degrees]},
                xmin= 10^0, xmax=10^5,
                ymin=-90,ymax=90
                ]

%                \addplot [blue] coordinates {(1,0)(1e3,0)(1e5,-100)};
                \addplot[mark=*,color=blue] coordinates {(3000,-45)};
                \vertLineFromPoint{3000,-45};
                \horLineFromPoint{3000,-45};
                \end{semilogxaxis}
        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]